# Загрузка изображения на сервер на Nativescript

Tags: php, javascript, nativescript

Добрый день. Пытаюсь писать на Nativescript. Хочу загрузить фото на свой сервер PHP. Пробовал разные способы но способ который хоть что то присылает на сервер вот такой:

```
function sendImages(uri, fileUri) {

imageName = fileUri;

var request = {
    url: "URL файла на сервере",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "ENCTYPE":"multipart/form-data",
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data",
        "File-Name": imageName,
        "Charset": "UTF-8"
    },
    description: "{uploading:"+imageName+"}"
};

var task = session.uploadFile(fileUri, request);

task.on("progress", logEvent);
task.on("error", logEvent);
task.on("complete", logEvent);

function logEvent(e) {      
    console.log("----------------");
    console.log('Status: ' + e.eventName);
    console.log('Error: ' + e.error);

    // console.log(e.object);
    if (e.totalBytes !== undefined) {
        console.log('current bytes transfered: ' + e.currentBytes);
        console.log('Total bytes to transfer: ' + e.totalBytes);
    }  
}
return task;
}
```

В итоге после выбора изображения в приложении я делаю `var_dump($_POST)` на сервере и получаю следующее

```
array(11) {
 ["яШяб"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzѓ„…†‡€‰Љ’“”•–—™љўЈ¤Ґ¦§Ё©ЄІіґµ¶·ё№єВГДЕЖЗИЙКТУФХЦЧШЩЪбвгдежзийкстуфхцчшщъяД"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ѓ„…†‡€‰Љ’“”•–—™љўЈ¤Ґ¦§Ё©ЄІіґµ¶·ё№єВГДЕЖЗИЙКТУФХЦЧШЩЪвгдежзийктуфхцчшщъяЪ"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["бПyUљVчЎI4е~ьЦґ№\Zoд
_лЫЏя"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["гJMКK^ј­їv*Ri?›hўЉgдБEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEP_J~О±‡‡х
GсgгЭпЩtЖ·ыMѕущдаџ6y8*¤rq‚OjтЩПАцџю8x{ВЊBKiпјЛЁЫЈЕґ®§ШЄшЧµБDю)ji«iџt«¦ЉНmыRHО¬Y–$oe_2КzЁВwШэsГЬ›'Бd8о,О(*ф°Ь°§MЫ–udЧД›ХGљ-¦¤њdЭ›ЌџAuыFюВЮи~шom}gk\iю…•±юЬЕYыуО}jн‡Ѓbя"]=>
  string(169) "hеHкҐгЦ®йж8zр®ЙРtТ‚ЉkHоУKH№sҐї ±їсЇаПЉѕшЪ_ш—lЁWН±ѕ‰HЋкH3Рс‚ЅЏЁБ;їІOВk?‹я lґmfЬK¦iс5юЈt’4 ,gЩќђэТХпЯµН–•с‹цOУ>0ЫЪЄ\ЩЕi9(“нЋXіиФџъж ђя ‚iЕl|Mв№9lmU}ҐдЭъ…э)"
  ["Ъ;kр6CCЕ,і‚|Ш,Z§€‚’m{7Н/fщµj\–WЧ–IJн6ПЫЧгЦЁъпь(П   ЯµЅ•¤(ъСЃ¶™¤a№`8юR¤Ћ„°оЧМµШ~Р7—_ь]-щ>`свьЗ8U™ХGэтqфв¬Џ€с77ЗgsЏћ*Wцu'J__Fе(Е$Ы¶ЬОЦNR”­vВѕ‚эѓѕ:jѕсдхЛч“HЦK‘І-nЂ$mфWБR?јTъззЪи~НymсkГ3йьОћ І0Њхo"]=>
  string(317) "p)џ5ГщЦ/‡sЄ–ыф¤¤µjйomydЇwM®§{ыk|(Ішaсћk­ФE§k°эєЮ4X¤,DЁ=б» p;WђЧХ?рSЎай‚Џ0ќAIцgя щZ”v>ПЕьв6>ќтЕК3·ч§N3“щКMьфР(ўЉgжЎEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEP¤юИ:х—‡?i/ЯЯИ9.¤¶З<РЙгОЈс®лю
'б
KLші§шИДЖПTТ–$—°–"
  ["`ЛнтІДъWПцЧwЭЪLСЛ‡ЋDl2°9Ды'б‡Ж/„_µзГTшUс‰ ѓ]UPСЙ_‰§•AqlЗшъе"]=>
  string(346) "ИБ^Ёэ‡ГмГ.ОxgБшЪсўс5(NzAUЌЇJъsЁЕGOжJтqЊѕ3§G“H°Г;і ЄЈ$“Р_Jш—ю   µвшх7я „;в6ќ5™l§ц”2G"ЏC°0cпЗРWgр§цFш]ы:°ш©сѓЖЦ··y[Йp‚ [W!ЂbLІqтфзўдEР°ЮсЗЧy1Р…<[s­*”Ь#Э№ЩKљЦWIЁфжqWiЯ¬ЗВїШ6ЧАъбЯKa§ЩyDя ЛЗ’ИїЂI?*сџШKв§Ѓю:Е¤кs€нµыF°Зf,#х,»»Х/ЪГцЋЏ,ЉЛAY!рю”МєzH0ЧxiШvИ (<Ѓћ„‘^QУ[L—тґrFБ‘С€*AИ Ћ†„ґ0гЋ/АSг<|ЌуQЛЎF•)6Ъ©м[•Э№]›|®ПЮK™4Ґeнї·oВќCБ_"
  ["сЕµ«fx€    Ј•WеK…P%B}Nып>†јBѕ»ш9ыIь,эЎ|я"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["WAШy‘†хЪґ“¶Њъ$аXшЃЉџp„ЈUVjUh9Ж5)T•Ь›SiZRMьZ¶щ9ЎЄщ‚ЅЏц!шSЁ|@шСiвimЏцg‡o_f_БgЙ@Ѕјnъ!ц®лБїрMЅyп’_€­"¶RГЈВТ;Ћа<ЃB}v·Тєя"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ќЅе¬љM$“sЏ–БA|kвЏЊЮУо‘x~ЗЛ©Иќо?ѓон^
Sj:ЌюЇЁП«j—rOss3Kq<­–‘Ш’МOrI"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Ў¦•‘щqn_в<NkV<®¬®—h¤ЈЯVўў›конЁQEПњ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
(ўЂ
_д}(ўЂ:­#г§ЖЅПы?GшЇЇБ"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Перерыл много разных источников и перепробавал различные советы, но так и не смог получить изображение из этого символьного месива.
Может быть кто-нибудь знает что нужно написать в файле на сервере для сохранения картинки. Или как всё таки правильно передавать изображения на сервер в Nativescript?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax.

Answer (score 2):

Для таких данных как изображение в `Content-Type` лучше использовать `multipart/form-data`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - можно использовать если у Вас буквенно-числовые данные.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data) объясняется это подробнее, но на английском.

Comment: Посмотрел что пишут в существующих библиотеках для загрузки изображений и обработке GET/POST запросов. В `Content-Type` передают `application/octet-stream`. Вот [пример](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-background-http) библиотеки для загрузки файлов на NativeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что без `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` вообще ничего не приходит на сервер. Насколько я понял этот заголовок нужен для передачи данных на сторонний сервер по XmlHttpRequest. А в данном случае я использую именно такой тип запроса к серверу, т.к. другие в Nativescript вроде как и не работают.